# Why is this guy blocking the rear wheel?

Tags: downhill

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOEDaqmrFq0&t=21m33s) the guy has clearly blocked his rear brake, as we can see the rear wheel is not rolling, but sliding. In this particular context, what has been his intent? Could have he done it for stopping, control/steering, look-cool-move?

Comment: Red Bull give you wings and locks up your rear wheel.  Base technique on what people do in a race not a commercial.

Comment: Some people have no respect for their environment, and give others who do the same sport a bad name. It's called being immature.

Comment: It's not for efficiency. You don't ride freeride for efficiency. Just fun on a bike. BTW it's one of my favourite MTB videos ever!

Comment: @andy256: that guy in the video has probably done more good for the sport than bad by skidding.

Comment: @cherouvim The groove he's cutting will become a channel when it rains, causing erosion. Is he going to going to go back and repair the damage?

Answer (score 2):

No reason at all.

NWD10 is a classic old school movie. You don't see purposeless skidding like that in today's  MTB movies nor do you see it in real life MTB riding. Kirt Voreis (the guy in that scene - legendary rider) is probably doing this for no reason, just for fun, or at least what used to be fun in these old times.

Comment: So there is some kind of fashion/trend about what is fun and what is not? Woah!

Comment: No. My fun me may be different from your fun. Skidding like that destroys the trails and it is not cool. People involved into trail building (either legal or illegal) have made sure to let everyone know, so people nowadays generally try to skid less, or not at all, especially where it is not needed. In addition, skidding without a reason destroys the tyre, the brake pads, your fingers (contributes to arm pump, which is something you don't need when you've got a full day of riding ahead) and heats up the brakes which makes them fade (not work properlly). For those reasons people skid less now.

Comment: All that may be true @cherouvim, however, during a actual race, more consideration maybe given to what techniques are most likely to lead to a win.

Comment: @ChrisinAK: The video doesn't show a race.

Comment: @cherouvim No one suggested it did.

Answer (score 0):

In my estimation, the initial section was just lockup during heaving brake application during the descent (stopping as much as possible, and desiring more stopping force than the friction of the tire has to offer causing lockup).

The lockup during the slide looks to have been done for more of a cool move, similar to using the parking brake to slide in a car. More cornering force can be applied from a non-locked wheel, so if his desire was to corner better then he wouldn't lock (intentionally).

However, this could also just be the rider's 'style', or by contrast, completely unintentional, as motives are hard to discern from actions. I'm just basing this on my own trail riding; I do occasionally lock up unintentionally on descents, but sliding sideways is typically intentional.

Comment: I have seen this in many FR videos, mainly on dusty open descents, where it's clearly intentional. I'll assume it is for the show, and without regard for the caused erosion.

Comment: It is without regard for the erosion, but it isn't necessarily for show.  If you watch any WCDH race, you'll see it's a completely valid method of control in some situations.

Comment: @ChrisinAK: I've been watching WCDH for 5 years and nobody skids for such a period of time on such "flat" terrain. As a matter of fact nobody at top 50 ever skids for more than half second.

Comment: @cherouvim Then perhaps it is the slow motion of the skids (two) that are confusing you.  He pretty clearly locks up his rear wheel twice trying to bleed speed on a very uneven and loose section of trail.

Answer (score 0):

Between the uneven surfacing and the loose dusty dirt, I'd say this was purposeful use of the [rear brake for control](http://sheldonbrown.com/brakturn.html).  There are times when using the front brake is more likely to cause a crash (like when your front wheel is digging back and forth through a trench) and rear wheel braking is more appropriate.  It appears at the very end of the section, he is taking a turn.  I'd guess between the uneven trenches and loose, dry dirt, he decided to dump some speed.  There are actually at least two wheel locks in the video.  One early and the second where the trench keeps the wheel from sliding out and he tracks the front wheel along the high trail between the two trenches.

Despite what others have answered here, power sliding or drifting is often the most efficient way to corner on loose surfaces, which is why the parking brake is used so liberally in car rally racing.  On a bike it can be difficult because the front wheel is nearly impossible to control in a slide.  The rear wheel is much more manageable, however, and rear wheel slides to maintain control of speed, or cornering are used by many top riders in more technical mountain bike disciplines.

Comment: The dude is not changing direction. He is just skidding down fully locked on a straight line for no reason.

Comment: No one suggested he was trying to change direction.  He is trying to bleed speed.  The trail is loose and uneven and he is going pretty fracking fast.  I'll assume touching the front brake would have sent him down.  It looks like he may have been about to enter a turn and wanted to drop some speed.

Comment: Here is why I doubt this is correct. His front wheel is on *even, flat* section outside of the trench. He could be using that, instead of shredding through the trench. When you are struggling to get your rear tire over an obstacle (the trench wall), you don't apply the break on it. Or maybe just he did this section 10 times and the photographers decided skidding was the coolest. BTW someone downvoted all answers to the question, lol.

Comment: Just normal downhill riding using the back brake for control on a dusty rutted trail. Nothing out of the ordinary or spectacular.

Comment: @Vorac I don't think he was struggling at all.  I think he just needed to dump some speed before turning.  Trying to dump it by braking with the front on loose dirt and risking it locking up as it plowed through those ruts would be disastrous.  Much better to let it track on the smooth section and lock the rear a couple times and let it drag where ever it was wont.